# Pyspark multiple when condition and multiple operation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on some data, where I need to run multiple conditions and if those conditions match then I want to calculate values to a new column in pyspark. I appreciate if any of you can help me in this regard.

```
block2.withColumn("Duration", when((col("START_TS")== col("REP_WORK_DAY_TS")) & ((col("END_TS")== col("REP_WORK_DAY_TS")),(unix_timestamp("END_TIME") - unix_timestamp("START_TIME"))))).show(5)
```

For example in the above code, I am applying two conditions and then I want to calculate the timestamp difference from start to end. For some reason, I am getting an error that "TypeError: Column is not iterable".

Comment: it looks like your parenthesis are mismatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem with your parenthesis.

```
block2.withColumn(
    "Duration",
    when(
        ( col("START_TS") == col("REP_WORK_DAY_TS") )
        & ( col("END_TS") == col("REP_WORK_DAY_TS") ),
        (unix_timestamp("END_TIME") - unix_timestamp("START_TIME"))
        )
).show(5)
```